# What is the difference between 付ける and くっ付ける?

Tags: word-choice

What does くっ change to the meaning?

Answer (score 2):

つける　~ join, put, wear... it means to put one thing onto one another.

くっつける ~ stick... so it means to put something onto one another so that it does not come off.

The くっ from くっつける comes from 食い.

https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/60197/meaning/m0u/%E9%A3%9F%E3%81%84%E3%81%A4%E3%81%8F/

Answer (score 2):

`くっ` is a variant of the prefix `食{く}い～`. So the original form would have been 食い付ける.

When a verb is prefixed with the morpheme `食い～` (or variants like `くっ～`), it adds an additional meaning to the base verb. As is obvious from the kanji, this can be the addition of a literal action of eating, chewing, or using the mouth/teeth. But it can also be a figurative meaning which adds an idiomatic sense to the base verb. From the examples below, you can see that the prefix `食い～` seems to add volition and/or intensity to the original action. It is as if conjuring up the image of teeth brings with it a certain ferocity which lends a sense of struggle (or at least intent) to that original verb.

> **込{こ}む** be crowded →   **食{く}い込{こ}む**　encroach, erode, bite into
>
> **つける** attach　→ **くっつける** stick together
>
> **しばる** fasten → **食{く}いしばる** clench one's teeth
>
> **つぶす** crush → **食{く}いつぶす** eat yourself out of everything
>
> **入{い}る** go in →　**食{く}い入{い}る** encroach upon
>
> **ちぎる** tear up → **食{く}いちぎる** bite off
>
> **とめる** stop → **食{く}いとめる** hold back
>
> **さがる** step back → **くいさがる** cling to, hold back, doggedly oppose
>
> **違{ちが}う** differ → **食{く}い違{ちが}う** clash with

*(All definitions from EDICT2 - [LINK](https://www.edrdg.org/cgi-bin/wwwjdic/wwwjdic?1E))*